# Spring Boot: How to Add Params to TestRestTemplate.postForEntity?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to add parameters to a `postForEntity` request but it seems to never go through. Here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String urlTemplate = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/test")
            .queryParam("update")
            // .queryParam("update", "{update}") //This does not work either
            .encode()
            .toUriString();

    HashMap<String, String> paramValues = new HashMap<>();
    paramValues.put("update", "true");

    HttpEntity<AnimateRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, new HttpHeaders());

    ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = this.template.postForEntity(
            urlTemplate,
            httpEntity,
            Boolean.class,
            paramValues);
    boolean bb = response.getBody();
}
```

In a controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> tester(@RequestParam(name="update", required = false) boolean rr)
{
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .body(rr);
}
```

Errors with:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
```

at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: when it is "optional", then why (small) `boolean` not `Boolean` or even `Optional<Boolean>` ?

Comment: @xerx593 Even with `Boolean` instead of `boolean` for the optional param, `response.getBody()` return null. With it as it currently is, it doesn't even exit the `postForEntity` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why, but the return contentType() in the controller return needed to be removed. For some reason Jackson was not parsing the return type properly. Then either a primitive `boolean` or the class `Boolean` works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Main problem, is that your implementation tries to respond with `text/plain` without registering any `Boolean` to `text/plain` converter.

You have several options to solve that:

1. Just return (response with) the "default (media) type":

   ```
   return ResponseEntity
    .ok()
    .body(rr);
   ```
2. If you *need* to respond with text/plain, then

   a. `ResponseEntity<String>` would be the straight-forward solution:

   ```
   @PostMapping(value = "/test2")
   public ResponseEntity<String> // String!!!  not Boolean ... {
     return ResponseEntity
      .ok()
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) // explicit media type here or as @PostMapping.produces attribute
      .body(String.valueOf(rr)); // convert the boolean here
   }
   ```

   b. Or to *really* register a custom(ized) (Boolean<->text/plain) converter ...

Then we could test 1. (with TestRestTemplate) like:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() throws URISyntaxException {
      final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/test/";
      URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
      // true:
      ResponseEntity<Boolean> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri + "?update=true", null /*here goes normally the "post body"/entity*/, Boolean.class);

      assertThat(result.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
      assertThat(result.getBody()).isTrue();
    }
```

and 2. accordingly with string result:

```
    @Test
    public void test2() throws URISyntaxException {
      final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/test2/";
      URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
      ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri + "?update=true", null, String.class);

      assertThat(result.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
      assertThat(Boolean.valueOf(result.getBody())).isTrue();
    }
```

Please consider, we have several (out-of-the-box) options regarding "content encoding" and "how to pass this `update` parameter".

For brevity, simplicity and lack of need I omit any post objects and headers (`null`, which would go as the second method argument), and passed the only parameter as "URI parameter".

---

Also consider the note on [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), which could also be applied to `TerstRestTemplate`:

> **NOTE**: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the `org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient` which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.